# How to start using webserver for business

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, server, dedicated-hosting, business

As a software developer I want to start my own business and I have a question for web services.
Through years I was using a lot of shared hosting services, but now I need some detailed info as I haven't thought about the web server configuration so far because everything was set for me already.

As a fresh starter what do I exactly need to host my custumers web sites? More then one website...
Do I need dedicated server? Can you give me some links?
How many domains can I have on my server?
Can I create emails from cpanels normally for each customer?
Can I install e-commerce services on my server? What do I need for that?
How can I buy domains as a company for my customers?

Do you recommend my own server or the rented one for the start?
Any information is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: To give any meaningful answer to this question would require a lot more detail. How many sites are you talking about, what are they going to be running, what is the estimated volume of traffic, what is your budget etc etc.

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about going into Web Hosting biz. Which is good but you need to ask yourself a few questions before that.

Are you ready to take up a new biz which will consume your time 24x7?

Are you willing to learn and get into a whole new niche which will take up quite a good amount of time for learning?

Starting a hosting biz is just the small part, due to the high competition in its niche, the major part is making a name for yourself which is like the 80% part of this biz. Can you do that?

And many more questions which you need to evaluate based on your comfort and availability. Its  gonna take a while before you adapt yourself to this new field of hosting.

And a few starting tips I would recommend:

Get yourself a managed VPS to start with if the amount of websites are not many.
Specifics of the vps depends on the amount of resources your website will consume.
Start playing with REHL distro on your localhost.

[Ryno VPS Solutions](http://www.ryno.in)

This will be my recommended solution to start off with.

Domain reseller plans is not suggested to start off with as they are suggested to be introduced down the line.

Calculate your options and make the right choice. Good Luck

Comment: thank you for your answer..I don't think that I am ready for my own server which will take all of my time. Through some time I will have people who will be responsible for the server eventually. So you recommend VPS server solution? The main reason why I need server is because I have some applications that need MySQL databases. And of course when you make web app for someone they want to have a "website" which is fully working..so that's why I need a web hosting for my company.

Answer (score 1):

> As a fresh starter what do I exactly need to host my custumers web sites? More then one website...

Very subjective, and depends on the needs of their websites, what frameworks they are built on, how much traffic they get, etc. Really hard to say beyond them needing a domain and somewhere to host it. What you seem to be hinting at is a reseller service somewhere. A hosting platform with WHM might be a good place to start.

> How many domains can I have on my server?

That's something to ask the hosting company.

> Can I create emails from cpanels normally for each customer?

Typically yes, but once again, that's something you need to talk to the hosting company about.

> How can I buy domains as a company for my customers?

You'll need to find a service that allows you to become a domain reseller.

Sorry I can't be of more help, but a lot of these questions are ones that need to be answered or discussed with the hosting company you are with/are looking to be with, and are also very dependant on both what your clients need and what your hosting company provides.

Comment: Thank you. I would really need more detailed answer...you really gave me an answers that I already know :)

Comment: I would definitely recommend contacting your host/future host then. We can't really give more detailed answeres given the vague questions. For example, "How many domains can I have on my server?" totally depends on what limits your hosting company has placed. "Do I need a dedicated server?" depends entirely on your specific needs. There are just so many factors.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need dedicated server? Can you give me some links?

No you don't usually need it unless you have thousands of sites or one extremely huge site.

> How many domains can I have on my server?

Domains usually unlimited (Can be just parked domains), if with the word domains you means sites, then with many hosters are unlimited too, but it's always written in the any web-hosting service the number of sites you can host on one plan.

> Can I create emails from cpanels normally for each customer?

Yes, obviously you can.

> Can I install e-commerce services on my server? What do I need for
>   that?

Yes, you don't need anything else that a web-hosting service, the same one on which you host your sites.

> How can I buy domains as a company for my customers?

See: www.onlinenic.com

> Do you recommend my own server or the rented one for the start?

If own server means that you buy a server and palce it in your office, it's a terrible idea! Buy a web-hosting service, in th form of shared hosting, or reseller hosting, or VPS.